# How to set Custom Response Header to Virtual Directory of Application in IIS?

Tags: iis, appcmd

I have `SMData` Application in my `Default Web Site`. I have added `attachments` virtual directory to `SMData` application. Now I want set `Content-Disposition` header for `attachment` virtual directory. I tried this, but no success:

```
SET XXXsiteNameXXX=Default Web Site
SET XXXappNameXXX=SMData

appcmd set config "%XXXsiteNameXXX%/%XXXappNameXXX%/attachments" -section:system.webServer/httpProtocol /+"customHeaders.[name='Content-Disposition',value='attachment']"
```

It is trowing error:

> Applied configuration changes to section
>   "system.webServer/httpProtocol" for "MA CHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default
>   Web Site/SMData/attachments" at configuration comm it path
>   "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/SMData/attachments" ERROR (
>   hresult:80070003, message:Failed to commit configuration changes. The
>   system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. 
I was creating virtual directory with this code:

```
SET XXXtaskDocumentsPathXXX="C:/docs"
%systemroot%/system32/inetsrv/APPCMD add vdir /app.name:"%XXXsiteNameXXX%/%XXXappNameXXX%" /path:"/attachments" /physicalPath:%XXXtaskDocumentsPathXXX%
```

Problem is in `/` in Path. Appcmd doesn't converting it to `\` when creating Virtual Directory. And for result Creating `web.config` is failing. I changed it to backslash and all started to work.